# opc .net api list of servers

Tags: .net, opc

I'm writing opc client on c#.
I want to get list of all opc servers on machine, how can i do it?
I'm using opc .net API from opc foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per example to list all OPC DA 2.0 servers on a specific machine:

```
public void GetServers()
{
    IDiscovery discovery = new OpcCom.ServerEnumerator();

    //Get all local OPC DA servers of version 2.0
    Opc.Server[] localservers = discovery.GetAvailableServers(Specification.COM_DA_20);

    //Get all OPC DA servers of version 2.0 of machine "MyMachine"
    Opc.Server[] hostservers = discovery.GetAvailableServers(Specification.COM_DA_20, "MyMachine", null);
}
```